# Memory leak in android application (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)/ use of onDestroy in activity

Tags: android

I have search a lot for **How to prevent android application from memory leaks ?**  but I couldn't find the right answer, the answers which I got involve lots of step. But not to the point.Form though answers I concluded that we have to destroy the object we created.
i.e object which garbage collector could not destroy.
so my question is **How to destroy object of Fragment/activity?**

Comment: `onDestroy()` gets called when they get destroyed.

Comment: What makes you so sure that your implementation of OnDestroy is the source of your memory leak? What code is actually executing when the OutOfMemoryError happens? (Please post a stack trace if possible). Also, specifically what cleanup do you want to happen in OnDestroy? What other things have you tried so far? Can you post code? We need a lot more information in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Keep in mind that Android specifically does *not* guarantee that OnDestroy will be called, so if you have some kind of saving or something that needs to happen don't use that method to do it. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Comment: @EJoshuaS - I'm build an app in which I used fragments  to replace each other in main activity to make my app UI flexible,but now when I open the main Activity an error is coming java.lang.outOfMemoryError- that main thread is doing heavy working ..So i want to destroy object by myself when the new activity is opened

Comment: Can you post an actual stack trace? If the OutOfMemoryException is happening during the activity itself OnDestroy won't help you; if it's when you switch to the new Activity make sure you call Finish() on your current activity. Also, why are you doing a long-running process on the UI thread?